# python writing to a blank file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am writing to a file and I asked someone to test it on their computer and they get a file with data.  When I run it I get a file but it is blank:
I have used f.close() and also f.flush but am still getting nothing.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import string
import csv

f = open('gropn1.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
file = open(os.path.expanduser(r"grt44.csv"),"wb")
file.write(b"Partno,Category,Sub1,Sub2,Desc"+b"\n")


partno2=link2=desc2=""



for row in csv_f:
    theurl="http://www.grote.com/?s="+row[1] + "&q1=1"
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")

    for partno in soup.find_all('h2',{"class":"single-product-number"}):
        partno2 = partno.text

    for link in soup.find('ul',{"class":"breadcrumbs"}).findAll('a'):
        link2 = link.text

    for desc in soup.find_all('h3',{"class":"additional-info"}):
        desc2 = desc.text

    CombinedString=partno2+","+link2+","+desc2+ "\n"

    file.write(bytes(CombinedString, encoding="ascii",errors='ignore'))


f.close()
```

Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What are the two machines you ran this on?

Comment: I am on Windows but I am not sure what he ran it on?  Maybe Mac

Comment: That's an important piece of missing information, considering that's the only difference we see here. Are you *certain* the program was never changed from machine to machine?

Comment: What if you need to be logged on to view that page? You might add some `print()` statements to see if the HTML elements are being found.

Comment: Yes - it is the same from machine to machine.  Since then I have tried adding f.flush() and also some indenting but still nothing is writing.  I didn't think there would be a difference between the systems but I will ask what he is running.

Comment: I did also change it to a print() and it did work doing that

Answer (score 0):

I have created this a while ago, it may contain the information you need:

```
import random
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
for i in range(10000):
    name = random.choice(alphabet)
    file = open(name+'RespectesLesConsignes{}.TXT'.format(i),'w')
    for i in range(1000):
        file.write(str(random.choice((1,0,3))))
    file.close()
```

This one creates 10,000 files, but it basically demonstrates how to write in a file:

```
#You open a new file
file = open(name+'Name{}.TXT'.format(i),'w')
#You write in it
file.write("What you want in the file")
#You close it
file.close()
```